# Is this symbol a ξ(\xi) or ζ(\zeta)? What is the latex of this symbol?

Tags: greek

I am learning this [post](https://www.statlect.com/asymptotic-theory/empirical-distribution), and this is the first equation on that post.

[image: at]

I cannot tell it is a ξ (`\xi`) or ζ (`\zeta`).

Which one it is, how to render this symbol?

---

(if I need to split the following to a new post, please let me know)

PS:

With Bernard's help, I tried `\xi` and got

[image]

which is 100% reproducible [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/xbrcmcffsgbz).

It looks a little bit different, am I missing something?

```
\documentclass{ximera}

\author{Jane Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{My first section}

\begin{example}
\xi_n = [x_1 \dots x_n]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a ξ (lower case Ξ).. The LaTeX code is (in math mode) `\xi`.

Comment: "am I missing something?" Each font is unique.  Just as times and palatino look different, so does the `ξ` in different fonts

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for you comments. Is it possible to get the font info from this [post page](https://www.statlect.com/asymptotic-theory/empirical-distribution)

Comment: Your image looks a little like Times. Try `\usepackage{mathptmx}`.

Comment: @DavidPurton  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Where can the `ximera` class be found?

Comment: You shouldn't try and learn typesetting from that source: it is ugly as hell.

Comment: @egreg open this [url](https://www.overleaf.com/read/xbrcmcffsgbz) and click `ximera.cls` on the left panel

Comment: As far as I can see, the class loads no font package, so you get Computer Modern. If you prefer a Times-like font, add `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` to your document. By the way, I spotted a *very wrong* `\everymath{\displaystyle}` line in `ximera.cls` (and also the redefinition of `\lim` is disputable).